# Tailwind: How to create a loading: modifier/variant?

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a modifier for a button for when it's in a loading state.

Based on the documentation [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants), I added the following in my tailwind.config.js

```js
// I assume this is included in tailwindcss 
// and doesn't need to be installed separately
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
     // ...
    plugins: [
        plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
            addVariant('loading', '&:loading')
          })
    ],
};
```

I assume this allows me to add a string of `loading` in the class such that it will apply those styles. This doesn't seem to work though, what am I doing wrong?

```html
<!-- I assume this should be blue-600 -->
<button className="bg-blue-600 loading:bg-blue-100">
  This is a normal button
</button>

<!-- I assume this should be blue-100 since it has className, "loading" -->
<button className="loading bg-blue-600 loading:bg-blue-100">
  This is a loading button
</button>
```

Comment: Change `addVariant('loading', '&:loading')` into `addVariant('loading', '&.loading')` - dot instead of colon as it is not pseudo-class like `:hover` but an actual class name

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka Yeah you got it right! Thank you. Wanna post an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` sign points to an element with **THIS** variant applied, so it should be translated in CSS as "this element with class `.loading`". In your example `:loading` will be translated as `loading` state which is not valid

So it should be `addVariant('loading', '&.loading')` not `addVariant('loading', '&:loading')`

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
            addVariant('loading', '&.loading') // here
          })
    ],
};
```